# Master card hosted session integration issue with the session

Tags: session, payment-gateway, payment, payment-processing, mastercard

I am Working with Mastercard integration using a hosted-session method.

As per the documentation, I follow the steps showed in it but I got an error while getting the session from MasterCard API

URL to get session:

> https://na-gateway.mastercard.com/form/version/54/merchant/YOUR-MERCHANTID/session.js

Error:

> { "errors": {"message": "System error. Support code: 26KANG2DC2X2E"}, "status": "system_error" }

Update 1:
Link to the documentation:

> https://na-gateway.mastercard.com/api/documentation/integrationGuidelines/hostedSession/integrationModelHostedSession.html

The full step by step process of integration is shown in document.

Comment: It's probably worth adding a link to the documentation, and telling us which steps for followed

Comment: @mattfreake I have updated the question as you asked for documentation. please check "update1".

Comment: Just to be sure - are you replacing YOUR-MERCHANTID with your merchant id? If I hit the URL above with the String "YOUR-MERCHANTID" in it, I get a System error too, suggesting your id is wrong

Comment: Did that resolve your issue @karan shah? Can you update the question if it did, as it may help others in future with the same problem

Comment: @mattfreake I have used my merchant id in the place of "YOUR-MERCHANTID".
I have just replaced just for security purposes because this is a public platform and merchant id is sensitive data. so this one not an issue.

Comment: Fair enough. I can only suggest your contact Mastercard then, because what you're doing looks fine to me